# MySQL select id from 10 rows for each different foreign key from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I got a table called messages and it contains a primary key "id" and a foreign key "foreign_id".
Many message rows can have the same foreign key. 
I want to query the table and return a limit of 10 ids for each different foreign key.

Here is a pseudoquery as i have to write some code here:

```
SELECT id FROM messages WHERE is_unique(foreign_id) LIMIT 10
```

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: Not sure `SELECT id FROM messages WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT foreign_id FROM messages) LIMIT 10` because it's hard to say without example table, data and expected output..

Comment: Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested query:

```
SELECT id
FROM messages
GROUP BY foreign_id
LIMIT 10
```